# Facebook Share OG Tags Not Working Properly

Tags: angular, facebook, server-side-rendering, facebook-share

I am trying to use Facebook Share on my Angular website.  To do this, I have implemented Angular Universal and created an SEO Service to generate the OG tags.  When I try to share a given URL, I receive a '404 Not Found' error message.

What is very strange is that when I inspect my web page content, I can see the og meta properties displaying just fine.

I have attached the relevant code and screenshots.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance,

```js
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { FirebaseService } from './../../firebase.service';
import { AngularFirestore } from '@angular/fire/firestore';
import { SeoService } from './../../seo.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-view-work',
  templateUrl: './view-work.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./view-work.component.scss']
})
export class ViewWorkComponent implements OnInit {

  item: any;

  constructor(
    public firebaseService: FirebaseService,
    private router: Router,
    private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private db: AngularFirestore,
    private seo: SeoService
  ) {
    this.route.data.subscribe(routeData => {
      /* tslint:disable:no-string-literal */
      const data = routeData['data'];
      if (data) {
        this.item = data.payload.data();
        this.item.id = data.payload.id;
      }
    });

    this.seo.generateTags({
      title: 'View work',
      description: 'Unique, handmade ceramic pieces',
      image: '/src/assets/images/olga_goldin.jpg',
      slug: `view-work/${this.item.id}`
    });
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.data.subscribe(routeData => {
      /* tslint:disable:no-string-literal */
      const data = routeData['data'];
      if (data) {
        this.item = data.payload.data();
        this.item.id = data.payload.id;
      }
    });
  }

  getShareURL() {
    return `https://fygpractice.com/view-work/${this.item.id}`;
  }


}
```

```html
<div class="container-desktop">
    <div class="text">
        <mat-divider></mat-divider>
        <h5 class="header">Name</h5>
        <h5 class="item">{{item.title}}</h5>
        <mat-divider class="divider"></mat-divider>
        <h5 class="header">Description</h5>
        <h5 class="item">{{item.description}}</h5>
        <mat-divider class="divider"></mat-divider>
        <h5 class="header">Price</h5>
        <h5 class="item">${{item.price}}</h5>
        <mat-divider class="divider"></mat-divider>
        <h5 class="header">Materials</h5>
        <h5 class="item">${{item.materials}}</h5>
        <mat-divider class="divider"></mat-divider>
        <h5 class="header">Dimensions</h5>
        <h5 class="item">{{item.height}}" x {{item.width}}" x {{item.depth}}"</h5>
        <div class="buttons">
            <a mat-raised-button color="warn" href="{{item.etsy}}">Purchase</a>
            <img class="facebook" src='./../../../assets/images/facebook_blue_50.png' shareButton="facebook" url="{{getShareURL()}}">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="image">
        <img mat-card-image src={{item.downloadURL}}>
    </div>
</div>
```

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Meta, Title } from '@angular/platform-browser';


@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class SeoService {

  constructor(private meta: Meta, private titleService: Title) { }

  generateTags(tags) {
    // default values
    tags = {
      title: 'Angular SSR',
      description: 'My SEO friendly Angular Component',
      image: 'https://angularfirebase.com/images/logo.png',
      slug: '',
      ...tags
    };

    // Set a title
    this.titleService.setTitle(tags.title);

    // Set meta tags
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:card', content: 'summary' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:site', content: '@angularfirebase' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:title', content: tags.title });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:description', content: tags.description });
    this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'twitter:image', content: tags.image });

    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'fb:app_id', content: 'xxx[![enter image description here][1]][1]' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:type', content: 'article' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:site_name', content: 'AngularFirebase' });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:title', content: tags.title });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:description', content: tags.description });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:image', content: tags.image });
    this.meta.updateTag({ property: 'og:url', content: `https://fygpractice.com/${tags.slug}` });
  }
}
```

Comment: What URL are you trying to share?

Comment: It is a dynamic URL, but here is one example - http://www.fygpractice.com/view-work/C37bQ4DMwgAnCa8N0XpW

Comment: This is what Facebook you send to Facebook https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/echo/?q=http%3A%2F%2Ffygpractice.com%2Fview-work%2FC37bQ4DMwgAnCa8N0XpW

Comment: Thank you WizKid.  So I am actually aware of that - I was hoping to find a resolution to why it is doing so because I don't see any issues with my code.

Comment: Probably need to debug your server. I get the same 404 error when I load the URL like Facebook gets.

Comment: feels like all your subpages getting 404? if that's the case check whether mod_rewrite is enabled in your server if its apache. just a thought!

Comment: Thank you for the tip!! I will look into that.